# Generate Token using the Flutter Application - Agora

Tags: flutter, agora.io

Is there any way to generate a Token from Flutter application and then validate it?

I tried passing `null` in `Token` parameter of `AgoraRtcEngine.joinChannel(null, widget.channelName, null, 0);` but it is showing black screen for the Audience

Already gone through:

- https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart
- https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/token_server_rtm

and other official docs but there's nothing to help in Flutter.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Token should not be generated on client side. There may be a rest API or if you're sending your channel name to some server, the response you're getting must include a token so you can pass to Agora Engine for joining channel.

Comment: Actually there is no such thing, no restAPI no method to do any thing. For every other language they have mentioned a method commonly named as `buildToken` which returns a token but for Flutter there no such method at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A token needs to be generated using your own server irrespective of the platform you're using. You can have a look at this guide that explains how to build your own server: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-token-server-using-golang/

You can have a look at this gist that explains how to use tokens in your Flutter code:
Using tokens - https://gist.github.com/Meherdeep/25d4bdac5dad0c4547809754c9e8417e
Renew tokens - https://gist.github.com/Meherdeep/088c5700f141d27b5e849d466c2358fb

Comment: Yeah thanks for answer actually I reached this stuff recently :)

Comment: Hi @meherdeep thakur, I managed to build my own local server using the link you provided. However, if I were to make it a production app, I won't be able to use the local server(it seems more for testing) right? Can you kindly share with me how you would go about deploying a server token for a production app? Thanks!