# How to Generate Server Token in Flutter Production Application for Agora

Tags: flutter, agora.io

How can I generate an Agora server token for my Flutter application in a production app?

I was following the post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66987841/15630845) and managed to run on the local server to generate the server token. However, if I were to make it a production app, I won't be able to use the local server.

How you would go about deploying a server to get server token for a production app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find many resources online on how to deploy a go lang server to a platform of your choice. You can also have a look at this [blog](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/connecting-to-agora-with-tokens-flutter/) from Agora which discusses how to deploy a token server on Heroku with just a single click and integrate it into your Flutter application.